# listing objects from ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-templates, many-to-many

I am trying to print a list of all the Conferences and for each conference, print its 3 Speakers.

In my template I have:

```
{% if conferences %}
        <ul>
        {% for conference in conferences %}
                <li>{{ conference.date }}</li>
                {% for speakers in conference.speakers %}
                        <li>{{ conference.speakers }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
{% else %}
<p>No Conferences</p>
{% endif %}
```

in my views.py file I have:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from youthconf.conference.models import Conference

def manageconf(request):
        conferences = Conference.objects.all().order_by('-date')[:5]
        return render_to_response('conference/manageconf.html', {'conferences': conferences})
```

there is a model named **conference**. which has a class named **Conferences** with a *ManyToManyField* named **speakers**

I get the error:

```
Caught an exception while rendering: 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable
```

with this line: `{% for speakers in conference.speakers %}`

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You need to call `all` on the many-to-many field to get an iterable object. Also, the next line should contain the speaker rather than `conference.speakers`.

```
{% for speaker in conference.speakers.all %}
        <li>{{ speaker }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) wasn't far as i was thinking!

Comment: What if in my view I wish to transform the ManyRelatedManager to a list to pass in a query?

Answer (score 23):

Similar inside pythoncode this would be:

```
for speaker in conferenece.speakers.all():
  print speaker.FIELDNAME
```