# Django Templates - Printing Comma-separated ManyToManyField, sorting results list into dict?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a Django project for managing a list of journal articles. The main model is `Article`. This has various fields to store things like title of the article, publication date, subject, as well as list of companies mentioned in the article. (`company` is it's own model).

I want a template that prints out a list of the articles, sorted by category, and also listing the companies mentioned.

However, I'm hitting two issues.

Firstly, the `company` field is a ManyToMany field. I'm printing this successfully now, using the `all` iterable, thanks to this SO question =). (Curious though, where is this `all` iterable documented in the Django documentation?)

[listing objects from ManyToManyField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759520/listing-objects-from-manytomanyfield)

However, I'd like to print ", " (comma followed by space) after each item, **except** the last item. So the output would be:

```
Joe Bob Company, Sarah Jane Company, Tool Company
```

and not:

```
Joe Bob Company, Sarah Jane Company, Tool Company,
```

How do you achieve this with Django's templating system?

Secondly, each `Article` has a CharField, called `category`, that stores the category for the article. I would like the articles sorted by Categories, if possible. So I use QuerySet, and get a nice list of relevant articles in article_list. I then use the `regroup` template tag to sort this into categories and print each one.

```
{ 'tennis': ('article_4', 'article_5')
  'cricket': ('article_2', 'article_3')
  'ping pong': ('article_1')
}
```

However, I need to make sure that my input list is sorted, before I pass it to `regroup`. My question is, is it better to use the `dictsort` template-tag to sort this inside the template, or should I use QuerySet's `order_by` call instead?

And I assume it's better to use `regroup`, rather than trying to code this myself in Python inside the view?

Cheers,
Victor

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**first question**

Use the python like join filter

```
{{ article.company.all|join:", " }}
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#join

**second question**

> My question is, is it better to use
>   the dictsort template-tag to sort this
>   inside the template, or should I use
>   QuerySet's order_by call instead?

I would use QuerySet's order_by. I like doing such stuff in DB. Beacuse with a huge dataset you could use database indexes.

> And I assume it's better to use regroup, rather than trying to code
>   this myself in Python inside the view?

regroup. It is defintly better to use python native functions.

Answer (score 18):

Try `forloop.last` for your first question

```
{% for company in article.companys.all %}
  {{company.name}}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Upvoted you =). However, I was curious - is this method superior in any way to the "join" templatetag in the other solution?

Comment: I think they are for two different uses. If you have just a string or int array, than use join. If you have an object that you have to iterate through, you have to use this method.

Comment: Also useful when you want to do something like:
`{% for company in article.companys.all %}

  <ahref="{{ company.get_absolute_url }}">{{company.name}}</a>{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}

{% endfor %}`