# Insert comma between list of element

Tags: django, html, django-templates

I have a list of events (with links) that I want to show as comma separated like

event1, event2, event3

I tried [the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177461/django-templates-printing-comma-separated-manytomanyfield-sorting-results-lis) but not working for me.

Here is the code :

```
<p> 

  {% for element in event.getelement.all() %}

       <a href="{{ build_absolute_url(url('main:home_getlink',link.uri)) }}">
        {{ element }} </a> 
     {% endfor %} 
</p>
```

Comment: You are *not* using Django templates. You seem to be using Jinja2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
<p> 
  {% for element in event.getelement.all %}
      <a href="{{ build_absolute_url(url('main:home_getlink',link.uri)) }}">
        {{ element }}
      </a>{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
  {% endfor %} 
</p>
```

Also, what's up with that `href`? Are you not using named routes whereby you can simply leverage the `{% url [route-name] [params] %}` tag?

Comment: I added the part but it does not insert comma :\

Comment: The only way that code wouldn't work is if there were no elements to iterate over.

Comment: It says forloop is undefined

Comment: it is working now .It seems forloop.last has been changed to loop.last

Answer (score 0):

This **shouldn't** be a function call since it is inside `template`. Change below,

```
{% for element in event.getelement.all() %}
```

with

```
{% for element in event.getelement.all %}
```

And for rest, the solution link you've posted should work after that.

---

**Edit:**

If you do this,

```
{{ event.getelement.all|join:", " }}
```

So this might produce result something like,

```
GetElement object, GetElement object, GetElement object
```

to get the value of a specific attribute you have to add the attribute as well. Something like this,

```
{% for e in event.getelement.all %}
    {{ e.<attr_name> }},
{% endfor %}
```

And this might produce something like,

```
event1, event2, event3,
```

Of course this is **not** an optimal solution because this is not the right way to do things when using any Framework.

---

**Optimal solution:**

What should be followed is that, do each and every logic in your `views` and send clean (pure) form of `data` to your `templates`. I mean send `lists`, `dictionaries`, `objects`, `tuples` should be sent to the `templates`. Hence creating a `list` of all the events and sending it `templates` though `context`.

**Note**: Following example is all based on assumptions.

**View:**

```
def xyz(request):
    event = Event.objects.get(name='xyz')
    context = {
       'event_elements': [e.name for e in event.getelement.all()]
    }

    return render(request, 'xyz.html', context)
```

**Template:**

```
{{ event_elements|join:", " }}
```

Now this will **definitely work**.

Comment: Can you post your `event` model ? And how  `event` and `getelement` are related with each other?

Comment: It is throwing a template syntax error 'Exception value: expected token 'end of print statement', got ':'  '